# É possível converter uma imagem para uma string no formato JSON?

Tags: java, json, image

Gostaria de saber se é possível converter uma imagem para uma string no formato JSON. Se sim, poderiam me explicar como? (se possível com códigos de exemplo).
Estou precisando fazer isso para enviar essas imagens para um webservice que será responsável por guardá-la no banco de dados.

Comment: Teoricamente você terá que converter a imagem em um array de byte (`byte[]`) e ai colocar dentro do seu `JSONObject`. Da uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726400/how-can-i-add-an-image-file-into-json-object)

Comment: Estou dando uma olhada, obrigado por responder. Vou tentar fazer algo aqui e depois posto o resultado.

Comment: @PauloH.Hartmann, consegui converter a imagem para um array de bytes. O problema agora é que a biblioteca que eu to usando `Gson` não faz conversão direta de um array de bytes para uma string JSON. Esse `JSONObject` que você mencionou só existe no android né?

Comment: Com a ajuda da biblioteca `Base64` você consegue passar esse seu array de bytes para uma `String`. Inicia uma novo objeto `Base64` e utiliza a função `encodeAsString(seuArrayBytes)`. Assim: `Base64 base = new Base64();
        String encoded = base.encodeAsString(byteArray);` (não tenho certeza disso, mas vale o teste)

Comment: `JsonObject` faz parte da biblioteca [gson](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html)`com.google.gson`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deixando a resposta aqui para quem passar pela mesma dúvida que eu tive.

```
    /*Primeiro, importa-se a imagem e a converte para um array de bytes*/
    BufferedImage imagem = ImageIO.read(new File("sua_imagem.jpg"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    ImageIO.write(imagem, "jpg", baos);
    arrayBytes = baos.toByteArray();

    /*Depois usamos a biblioteca Base64 para converter o array de bytes em uma string*/
    String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(arrayBytes);

    /*Por fim, utilizamos a biblioteca JSON Simple para criar uma string no formato JSON utilizando os dados do encoded que conseguimos ao converter o array de bytes com o Base64*/

    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("imagem", encoded);
    String jsonImagem = jo.toJSONString();
```